# How to get user's files in skydrive recursively using Microsoft LiveSDK?

Tags: sdk, onedrive, live-sdk

I want to get all files in user's account using live SDK APi.
I tried to use this query:

```
https://apis.live.net/v5.0/me/skydrive/files
```

It returns only top-level files and folders. I want to get all files in all folders in user's account.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the [new OneDrive API](https://dev.onedrive.com/items/view_delta.htm) to accomplish this. Specifically, the delta API will let you make a minimal number of calls to get the current state of the hierarchy - including all files and folders. It's also safer as it will report any changes in the item state as you perform the initial enumeration.